# Get csrftoken cookie with React

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios, csrf-token

I am making my first app with **React**, interacting with a **Django Rest Framework** back-end application. They both are running in their local servers.

I found that requests from the **React** front-end (that are sent with **Axios**) requiere a **csrftoken cookie**. I read and followed [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#ajax) about it, but I always get an `undefined` **csrftoken cookie**.

This is the code of the request:

```
handleClick() {
    var csrftokenCookie = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
    console.log(csrftokenCookie);

    const axios = require('axios');
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/es/api-auth/login/', {
      next: '/',
      username: 'some_name',
      password: 'secret'
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
```

I print to console the result of the `Cookies.get('csrftoken')`, and I can see that it is always `undefined`.

I don't know what I am missing in order to be able to get the **csrftoken cookie**.

Comment: You have revealed the username and the password of what you have sent a `POST` request

Comment: Was the problem just that you weren't adding your csrftokenCookie to your request as a header with key "X-CSRFToken"?